# Should this function be ran asynchronously on the server

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, logic

im not that experienced with node js but im developing something similar to how uber displays their cars in real time on a map.

So i have an sql database with a ton of cars and their gps location. The client sends their gps coordinates and a radius to the following function. some is in pseudo code for now.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "",
    port: ,
    user: "",
    password: "",
    database: ""
});

user.on('returnCars', function(gps, radius){    
     connection.query({
        sql: "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE radius = ?", 
            values: [username] },                   

                    function(error, results, fields) 
                    {           

                    if(results) 
                        {
                            user.emit('returnCars', results);
                        }
                    }
            });
     });
});
```

So as sql querys arnt instant, if there was 1000 people running this function at once it would surely clog up. All my research is telling me that this is the right way to do it so the only option would for it to be ran asnync right?

Also would it just be the returnCars function to run asynchronously? Im not sure if because the connection/ sql details variable isnt in a function or anything it would all try and read it at once so maybe it should go inside the function or something.

Comment: No matter if its async or not, the server has to do some work.

Comment: FWIW, if you want something like Uber, you probably want *realtime updates* as well; you don't want to query just once, you want to notify everyone as soon as the position is updated. This isn't going to work very well if it involves a database query. You need to look into websockets to *push* updates to clients. Clients would then in some sense *subscribe* to a certain area of interest. As soon as your server receives a position update, it forwards it to all relevant subscribers. No database query necessary in that process.

Comment: oh i never thought about it like that, at the moment I have it on a timer so every 5 seconds or so this function will run with the clients new gps, ill look into the method you said, i appriciate that thanks

Comment: You definetly should. Sending all positipns to every client every 5 secs might work for a few hundred positions / clients, but websockets can handle much more

Comment: ok, i dont suppose you can have links or anything on more detail about this? I cant find anything in terms of code

Answer (score 2):

The code is far too fragmentary to really help you with, but *in general*:

- If you're using Node's built-in HTTP serving or something layered on top of it like Express, your code for when a request is received is expected to run asynchronously and there's nothing special you need to do to make that happen.
- If you're using any of the main `npm` modules for MySQL access, the functions you use to make queries will run asynchronously and there's nothing special you have to do to make that happen.

In your pseudocode example, you've shown a callback for your `sqlQuery` function stand-in. That's likely how you would use the MySQL access module you choose to use, either with direct callbacks like that or promises.

Comment: oh sorry i am using express yes, Ive done mysql queries like this before, ill add some more code so its abit more clearer but if what your saying is it all runs async anyway, thats amazing, thanks